# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow' error occur

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running my first python Tensorflow programm in spyder IDE.  I have also change python interpreter preference but still I get

> ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow' error occur.

[image: ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow']

Comment: You need to provide more details as Python version and distribution and how you installed TensorFlow as its version. Also please provide the logs rather screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Check module is present in current working directory or in site-package folder or if you have downloaded at some other location include that path in path variable